# Manually change media width used for printing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, media-queries

When I preview/print a page, Bootstrap seems to apply the `-sm` layout breakpoint before printing, and I want it to use at least `-lg`.

So, my question is: is there any way to manually set which viewport width the browser will use when printing, without having to re-write all of my CSS to include `@media print` exceptions everywhere?

I've had this issue mostly on pages using Bootstrap, but it still applies to other frameworks, or even plain media-query usage.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code below.

```
 @media print {


.col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm- 
8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
float: left;
}

.col-sm-12 {
 width: 100%;
}

.col-sm-11 {
 width: 91.66666666666666%;
 }

.col-sm-10 {
  width: 83.33333333333334%;
 }

.col-sm-9 {
 width: 75%;
}

.col-sm-8 {
 width: 66.66666666666666%;
}

.col-sm-7 {
width: 58.333333333333336%;
}

.col-sm-6 {
width: 50%;
}

.col-sm-5 {
  width: 41.66666666666667%;  
}

.col-sm-4 {
 width: 33.33333333333333%;
}

.col-sm-3 {
 width: 25%;
}

.col-sm-2 {
 width: 16.666666666666664%;
}

.col-sm-1 {
 width: 8.333333333333332%;
}

}
```